# Security header is not valid error message

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm getting this message

> TIMESTAMP=2017-03-29T16:36:41Z&CORRELATIONID=9d5672f086c52&ACK=Failure&VERSION=204&BUILD=31674279&L_ERRORCODE0=10002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Security error&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Security header is not valid&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error

I'm sure that I'm using the right credentials, I've copied them from sandbox account, from `View API Signature` page.

I'm trying to connect to sandbox environment with the url `https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp`.
Here is how my payload looks like:

```
METHOD=MassPay&
USR=usr_api1.name.com&
PWD=9M8SWRPX6JMXDHAP&
SIGNATURE=AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AIajEwSIe41AAl--j033rVmjUPI7&
VERSION=204&
RECEIVERTYPE=EmailAddress&
CURRENCYCODE=USD&
L_EMAIL0=some.user%40company.com&
L_AMT0=25
```

And I have TLS1.2 enabled. Is there any way to trace the problem except for incorrect credentials? Or maybe I have to set-up my test/dev account? By the way, my dev account isn't Business, but test account is Business and not Client.

Here is code that makes the request:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var field in dic)
{
    sb.Append($"{field.Key}={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(field.Value)}&");
}
sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
var payload = sb.ToString().Trim();

var req = WebRequest.Create(SandBoxHost + "?" + payload);
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

using (var resp = req.GetResponse()){}
```

Comment: I know you say you're sure, but in the 15+ years I've been working on the PayPal API I've seen this error thousands of times and it's ALWAYS invalid credentials one way or another.  Double check the values, and make absolutely sure you aren't sending sandbox credentials to the live endpoint or vice-verse.

Comment: @AndrewAngell and I saw an answer on the same question where the problem was on PayPal side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credentials and URL were correct. However, I found out that you are not able to send Mass Payment via txt file if your sandbox Business account does not have verified credit card. You need to specify this moment when you are creating a new sandbox user. Guess it would not work with API as well if you don't specify credit card.

The real problem was in one of the field names. I used `USR` instead of `USER`.